# Why is Graph API Intermittently Working with the same input?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

When using the graph api in code or the online Graph Explorer a financial items picture is intermittently accessible. It works for a bit and then returns **BadRequest_NotFound** for an hour or more.

The exact same call in graph explorer will work sometimes (returning the picture metadata) and then return an error. This happens in code as well using the graph.beta api

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/financials/companies/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/items/67581b16-d67b-ed11-9989-000d3af32b3d/picture

[image: Graph Explorer GET]

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Comment: Beta APIs not expected to be used in production as it is not thoroughly tested and Microsoft itself doesn't recommend it.